# Good tool for storing server access details

Tags: web-server

Are there any common/good tools that you sys admin guys use to store lots of server access details i.e. ip addresses, logins etc.

Im getting by with text file at the moment but am considering moving to something more suited to the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about configuration details, you're looking for a CMDB of some sort - read the FAQ for why shopping questions are off-topic for ServerFault and how to better phrase the question so it's answerable. Some folks use plain old text files or spreadsheets, some people spend a crap-ton of money on discovery tools and databases. Depends on what you need and what your budget is, neither of which have you sufficiently explained.

A different and possibly better approach is to implement a configuration management system like Puppet or Chef or CFengine, to declare what the config should be on each server or group of servers and then execute so that the servers conform.

Answer (score 0):

IPPlan is a good tool to store server information (network interfaces, hardware details, etc.) based on network architecture. Credentials should be stored in an encrypted tool like keepass.